# Ambiguity in the definition of a simple function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have seen the definition for a simple function, $\phi:X \to \mathbb{R}$ where $$\phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i \chi_{A_i}(x)$$

This seems silly in my head but I was wondering if we could have for example a simple function such as $$\phi(n) = \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n}\chi_{ \{n\}}(n)  $$

This doesn't seem like it should be allowed since the coefficients aren't constants, but they are constant on the sets $\{n\}$.

Comment: Of course the coefficients are constants (that depend on the summation index $n$, which is totally fine).

Comment: $n$ is just the summation index, not the argument of your $\phi$. So this is a bona fide simple function with $c_n=\sqrt{n}$ and $A_n=\{n\}$.

Comment: I think the key point is whether something **CAN BE** expressed in the first form you gave, not whether it **IS** expressed in that form. As an analogy, both $\frac{2}{3} \div \frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{2\sqrt 8}{\sqrt 2}$ are rational numbers (i.e. can be expressed as the quotient of two integers), even though neither of these expressions is in the form of an integer divided by an integer.

Comment: so if $n$ was the argument of $\phi$ would this not be a simple function?

Comment: You are using $n$ for two different things in the second equation: it is both the argument of the function, *and* the index of summation. This means what you wrote doesn't work. If you change it to $\phi(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n}\chi_{\{n\}}(x)$, then that is a sensible definition. But as written, on the right hand side the same symbol is playing two roles, and you can't do that. What you have not is not a simple function because it is not even a function: it is a sequence of symbols that is nonsensical.

Comment: ok thanks for the clarification I thought it was silly

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Well, formally, this is a sound expression, it's just that the right hand side does not actually depend on $n$, since all occurences of $n$ there are bound (so it's just equal to $\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2+\ldots+\sqrt k$, regardless of $n$). Of course, valid or not, this is awful form for reasons clear from OP's confusion, if nothing else.

Comment: If the symbols confuse you, you should just keep in mind the alternative definition that a simple function is a measurable function with finite range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in the expression
$$\sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n}\chi_{ \{n\}}(n),$$
$n$ does not occur as a free variable. Therefore, upon fixing the parameter $k$, this becomes a constant (namely, $\sqrt 1+\sqrt 2+\ldots+\sqrt k$), not dependent on $n$ at all.

In particular, (having fixed $k$), the  formula $\phi(n) = \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n}\chi_{ \{n\}}(n)$ *does* define a simple function, just not a very interesting one.

It is *not* a constant, nor a simple function, when considered as a function of $k$, since there are infinitely many possible values.

Note that while the equation $\phi(n) = \sum_{n=1}^k \sqrt{n}\chi_{ \{n\}}(n)$ is formally correct, it is misleading, since $n$ is a free variable on the left hand side and it has no free occurences in the right hand side.

For a very similar example of this phenomenon in logic, consider the formula
$$
\varphi(x)=(x^2>1 \rightarrow \exists x(x^2<1)),
$$
or even just
$$
\psi(x)=\exists x(x^2<1)
$$
both of which are true for all real $x$, even those whose squares happen to be greater than $1$.

All of these examples are formally sound, but are considered bad form (precisely because they might cause confusion just like yours).

Finally observe that the related expression,
$$
\sum_{m=1}^k \sqrt{m}\chi_{ \{m\}}(n),
$$
does define (after fixing the parameter $k$) a simple function of the variable $n$. (which is zero for arguments outside of $\{1,2,\ldots, k\}$).